# Segmentation Fault: CS50 recover.c

Tags: c, cs50

This program accepts a filename as input and should recover all jpegs on that file. It reads 512 bytes at a time, checking for the start of a new jpeg.

The program compiles when I run it, but it gives a segmentation fault. Please advise me how I can go about fixing this.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // check for proper usage
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: 1 command line argument\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // check if file can be opened
    FILE *file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (file == NULL)
    {
        printf("Cannot be opened\n");
        return 2;
    }

    // read 512 bytes into buffer until end of card
    int buffer[128];
    int counter;
    counter = 0;
    char filename[8];
    FILE *img = NULL;

    while(fread(buffer, 4, 128, file) == 128)
    {
        //check if start of new JPEG
        if (buffer[0] == 0xff && buffer[1] == 0xd8 && buffer[2] == 0xff && (buffer[3] & 0xf0) == 0xe0)
        {
            //check if first JPEG
            if (counter == 0)
            {
                sprintf(filename, "%03i.jpg", counter);
                img = fopen(filename, "w");
                fwrite(buffer, 4, 128, img);
                counter += 1;
            }
            else if (counter > 0)
            {
                fclose(img);
                sprintf(filename, "%03i.jpg", counter);
                img = fopen(filename, "w");
                fwrite(buffer, 4, 128, img);
                counter += 1;
            }
        }
        else if (counter > 0)
        {
            fwrite(buffer, 4, 128, img);
        }
    }
    fclose(img);
    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The call `fread(buffer, 4, 128, file)` reads (as you rightly say) 512 bytes into the array of 128 integers. However, when you then test for the start of a new JPEG file in this code:

```c
if (buffer[0] == 0xff && buffer[1] == 0xd8 && buffer[2] == 0xff && (buffer[3] & 0xf0) == 0xe0)
{
    //...
```

you are inspecting the *low bytes of each of the first four integers* in the array, rather than (as you should be) checking the first **four bytes** of the array. These four bytes will all be in the **first** integer element (`buffer[0]`).

Thus, your program will never find the start of a new JPEG and, consequently, the `img` file will never be opened ... and you are then calling `fclose` with a `NULL` file pointer, which is undefined behaviour and likely to cause the segmentation fault you see.

Instead (assuming the correct 'endianness'), do the following check:

```c
if ((buffer[0] & 0xfffffff0) == 0xffd8ffe0)
{
    //...
```

To allow for the 'wrong endianness', you could check for either byte order in `buffer[0]`:

```c
if ((buffer[0] & 0xfffffff0) == 0xffd8ffe0 || (buffer[0] & 0xf0ffffff) == 0xe0ffd8ff)
{
    //...
```

Better still, just read (and write) the buffer for what it is - an array of 512 bytes, with code like this:

```c
unsigned char buffer[512];
//...
while(fread(buffer, 1, 512, file) == 512)
{
    //...
```

This way, you can keep your 'JPEG start' test as it is.

Comment: Thanks, this explanation really helped a lot. I made the necessary changes and the program runs smoothly now.

Answer (score 0):

`fclose(img)` is the culprit. `img` is NULL. In order to find out why, you can insert some `printf` after your `fopen`.  Here is the [link](https://cee.studio/200529-vAU/recover) to debug any segfaults in the future.

```
$ ./recover card.raw

  Memory access error: invalid parameter; abort execution.
  # fclose's parameter (0x0) is not a valid FILE pointer.
  # Stack trace (most recent call first) of the error.
  # [0]  file:/recover.c::55, 5
  # [1]  [libc-start-main]
```